# Password reset for user account

Tags: password

I am trying to reset password for a user account for which current password is lost. I am logged in as root but still it is asking for current password. How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? `passwd (username)`, when run as root, will not ask for the old password, for exactly that reason.

Comment: Most likely you are *not* logged in as root: try `id` to verify.

Comment: on _what system_?

Comment: I have checked everything. I logged in directly as root. No issues with passwd and shadow file. No faillogs. I have also tried to reboot the server. Still when I login as root and try to reset the password for a user account, it is asking for current password. Issue persists only for user accounts and not for admin accounts root and lmain.

Comment: Is it possible that you changed the permissions for root? Perhaps you corrupted the passwd file? Makes sure this is the first line in your /etc/passwd file: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Comment: I finally found the issue. I did not know that centrify was installed in the server. It has added some entries the /etc/pam.d/system.auth file. When I commented those entries, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

If you are logged in as root, then you simply type the new password twice. It will not ask for the old password. But you have to use the proper syntax:

```
passwd username
```

where username is the name of the user

i.e.;

```
root@Test:~# passwd someuser      
Enter new UNIX password:     
Retype new UNIX password:
```